# Stop function in if statement

Tags: jquery

I have a function to remove a row on a table when the user clicks on a delete button. If there are only two rows left (header and input row), I don't want the user to be able to delete it. I have tried return(false); and exit(); and neither work. I do get the alert but then the line gets deleted anyway.

I have the following jquery function below:

```
function deleteLine() {
  var $rowcount = $("#desc_table tr").length;
  if ($rowcount <= 2) {
    alert("Cannot remove all the description lines.");
    return (false);
  } else {
    $("#desc_table").on('click', '.btnDelete', function() {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
  }
}
```

Not sure if you need this but here is part of my html:

```
<tr>
  <td><input name="desc1" type="text"></td> 
  <td> <input name="desc_hr1" type="text"></td>
  <td> <input name="desc_rt1" type="text"></td>
  <td><input name="desc_amt1" type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="X" name="delete" class="btnDelete" onclick="deleteLine()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name="desc2" type="text"></td> 
  <td> <input name="desc_hr2" type="text"></td>
  <td> <input name="desc_rt2" type="text"></td>
  <td><input name="desc_amt2" type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="X" name="delete" class="btnDelete" onclick="deleteLine()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name="desc3" type="text"></td>
  <td> <input name="desc_hr3" type="text"></td>
  <td> <input name="desc_rt3" type="text"></td>
  <td><input name="desc_amt3" type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="X" name="delete" class="btnDelete" onclick="deleteLine()"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `onclick="return deleteLine()"`

Comment: @vicbyte that's irrelevant. try it.

Comment: I've already tried both syntax vicbyte - neither one changed the result. I also tried your change Kevin and it didn't work either. It's still deleting the last line.

Comment: You shouldn't be binding a click handler inside the `onclick` function. That sets up a function to call the *next* time you click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line adds an event handler to all the rows that short circuits your check:

```
$("#desc_table").on('click','.btnDelete',function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

With this they all now have a click handler that directly removes the row.

You can add a reference to the input with:

```
<input type="button" value="X" name="delete" class="btnDelete" onclick="deleteLine(this)">
```

And then use it to delete the rows:

```
function deleteLine(e){
    var $rowcount = $("#desc_table tr").length;
    if($rowcount <= 2){
        alert("Cannot remove all the description lines.");
        return ;
    }
    else{
       e.closest('tr').remove();
    }
 }
```

Of course, there are other ways too -- the important thing is to avoid adding a new click handler to all the rows.

Comment: Thank you Mark, this worked great. Didn't realise what I had was redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `onclick` attribute. Just delegate the click handler, and put the check there.

```js
$("#desc_table").on('click', '.btnDelete', function() {
  var $rowcount = $("#desc_table tr").length;
  if ($rowcount <= 2) {
    alert("Cannot remove all the description lines.");
    return (false);
  } else {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="desc_table">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="desc1" type="text"></td>
    <td> <input name="desc_hr1" type="text"></td>
    <td> <input name="desc_rt1" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="desc_amt1" type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="X" name="delete" class="btnDelete" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="desc2" type="text"></td>
    <td> <input name="desc_hr2" type="text"></td>
    <td> <input name="desc_rt2" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="desc_amt2" type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="X" name="delete" class="btnDelete"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="desc3" type="text"></td>
    <td> <input name="desc_hr3" type="text"></td>
    <td> <input name="desc_rt3" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="desc_amt3" type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="X" name="delete" class="btnDelete"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, This solution worked for me too. I went with Mark's above since that is the first solution I tried. Thank you for the response though! I would vote you up if I could...but I'm only at reputation 10. Someone knocked me down a couple on this question...not sure why.